# replacing zend placeholder contents from the view script

Tags: php, zend-framework

I initialize my placeholder like so:

**default.phtml (layout file)**

```
<?php $this->placeholder('hero')->captureStart(); ?>
<div class="primary">
  <h1>Foo bar!</h1>
</div>
<?php $this->placeholder('hero')->captureEnd(); ?>
<?php echo $this->placeholder('hero'); ?>
```

**index.phtml (view script file)**

```
<?php $this->placeholder('hero')->captureStart(); ?>
<div class="primary">
  <h1>Bar Baz!</h1>
</div>
<?php $this->placeholder('hero')->captureEnd(); ?>
<?php echo $this->placeholder('hero'); ?>
```

**Output:**
In my output i end up getting both headings. I just want Bar baz to display.

## Bar Baz!

## Foo Bar!

How do i just replace/override the contents inside my view script of the placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default setting for `captureStart()`[(Check Example #13)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder) is `append` trying setting it to `set`:

```
<?php $this->placeholder('hero')->captureStart('SET'); ?>
<div class="primary">
  <h1>Bar Baz!</h1>
</div>
<?php $this->placeholder('hero')->captureEnd(); ?>
<?php echo $this->placeholder('hero'); ?>
```